# How to define empty IndexedTables in Julia?

Tags: julia

I am unable to define empty IndexedTables, e.g.

```
using IndexedTables, IndexedTables.Table
t = Table(Columns(a=Int64[],b=String[]),Int64[])
t[1,"a"] = 1
t[1,"b"] = 2
t[1,"c"] = t[1,"a"] + t[1,"b"]
BoundsError: attempt to access 0-element Array{Int64,1} at index [0]
```

I am aware that creating the IndexedTable with already the data is more efficient that creating an empty one and then insert values, but sometimes you are obliged to go on this way.

Is this a bug ? If so, is there any workaround possible ?

(I already posted this thread on the [Julia forum](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-define-empty-indexedtables/6508), but so far I had no replies there)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably a bug in IndexedTables.

Inserting into an IndexedTable requires reindexing to access the data. Reindexing is done with `flush!`.

But `flush!(t)` fails in the example in the question with the empty `t`.

Fixing `flush!` which calls `_merge!` can be done by:

```
julia> function IndexedTables._merge!(dst::IndexedTable, src::IndexedTable, f)
    if length(dst.index)==0 || isless(dst.index[end], src.index[1])
        append!(dst.index, src.index)
        append!(dst.data, src.data)
    else
        # merge to a new copy
        new = _merge(dst, src, f)
        ln = length(new)
        # resize and copy data into dst
        resize!(dst.index, ln)
        copy!(dst.index, new.index)
        resize!(dst.data, ln)
        copy!(dst.data, new.data)
    end
    return dst
end

julia> t[1,"c"] = t[1,"a"] + t[1,"b"]
3
```

The change is the addition of the `length(...)` check in the first `if`.

Of course, a pull request / issue should be opened with IndexedTables.jl. Antonello, will you do this? (or shall I)

Comment: Thank you Dan Getz, I let you issue the pull request, as the one that found the root of the problem :-)

Comment: OK. Opened the PR

Comment: Just to note [the pr](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/IndexedTables.jl/pull/88) has been merged.